# Catching a return code from a non-interactive R script execution

Tags: r, scripting, batch-processing

I need to launch in batch some R processes and I'd like to catch a return code from the scripting language to understand if the R process had or not a poblem in its execution.

Generally speaking what I need is:

```
EXEC "R batch processing" 
IF RC<>0 THEN 
    EXEC recovery process 
    END
```

So my question is: could I exit from an R batch processing passing a return code to the caller?

Comment: I would write a wrapper script around the batch process. That way you have available all R structures to handle work flow.

Comment: To go more in detail, I'm using ObjREXX as scripting language. I know it's not probably so used ...

Comment: Within each script, you could write to stdout, and I'm guessing you could pick that up and handle the execution that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `quit` function in `R`, e.g. `quit(status = 1)` and then catch it in your batch script - you may need to google on how to do that in your scripting language.